# Obtaining angle of object in relation to camera direction

Tags: java, c++, camera, angle

What I'm trying to achieve is get the angle that an object is in relation to the direction the camera is facing.
From the image I've provided:
Point A: Camera position.
Point B: Reference point which is always in front of the camera's view regardless of rotation.
Point C: Object in question.

Geting the degrees between point B and C is already done, but the problem is that the yaw of my camera (in degrees) is according to world space and not in view(camera) space. This becomes problematic depending on which Cartesian Quadrant the camera position currently resides in.

How do I define degrees around the camera based on the camera's direction independent of world space?

[image]

Comment: your understanding is bound to be confused: you talk about world coordinates/space as if you are talking about 3D space; here we are talking about 2D space - the 2D plane - let that be clear; if it is otherwise you need to clarify that to your mind and to ourselves

Comment: There is no need to be condescending. Furthermore, same concept applies whether its 2D or 3D, except in 2D, its another entity instead of a camera. World space is no different than Earth. No matter where you stand, North is always North, West is always West, etc. But yourself on the other hand  have your own space. Your constants are your front, back, left, right, above and under you.  But you are special, because in relation to the world, you can rotate. So given the above img, if you are the camera and you rotated to 135 degrees, is point C to  your left or behind you? Its the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Your picture doesn't show it too well, because you're camera is positioned at the origin of the world. But if you were to imagine the camera somewhere else, like in the top-left, It's easy to see that the angle between the lines to B and C from the origin, is different than the angle between the lines to B and C from the camera.

By first subtracting the camera position from the vectors to B and C, you get 2 new vectors which represent the lines to B and C from the camera. As if the camera were the origin.

Computing the angle between those will give you the angle in camera space.

---

In pseudocode:

```
Vector b      // B's position
Vector c      // C's position
Vector camPos // camera's position

Vector bFromCam = (b - camPos)
Vector cFromCam = (c - camPos)

float angle = AngleBetween(bFromCam, cFromCam) // Compute the angle
```

I've left the implementation of computing the angle out, since you know how to do that already.

Comment: But is "angle" in relation to the world or in relation to the direction the camera is facing with that direction always being 0 degrees?

Comment: @SpicyWeenie Well, it's in relation to B, which is the direction the camera is facing. It's simply the angle between the line from the camera to B  and the line from the camera to C, like in your picture. An angle between 2 vectors can't really be _in relation to_ something else.

Comment: B is just an imaginary point of reference to mark which direction the camera is facing and used as the 3rd point to get the angle between B and C. But B also has the same purpose of marking what is 0 degrees in relation to the camera, which is the direction the camera is facing. To make a long story short, world space is no different than cardinal directions (N,S,E,W) and what Im trying to define is what is forward, left, right, back (0, 270, 90, 180), but in degrees. But this degrees rotate with the camera with 0 always being the direction the camera is facing.